# Define XAML resource contained in a class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I needed some help with the syntax to define a resource in XAML for a method in a seperate class. The line `<c:StatusToColour x:Key="MyConverter"/>` is giving me the following error

`The name "StatusToColour" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:ProjectXYZ".`

So it looks like it's not recognising `xmlns:c="clr-namespace:ProjectXYZ"` in XAML. Please can someone advise on the correct syntax?

**StatusToColour.cs:** (in the project root folder)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace ProjectXYZ
{
    public class StatusToColour : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {

        //more code
        }
    }
}
```

**MainControl.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ProjectXYZ.Content.MainControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:c="clr-namespace:ProjectXYZ"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <c:StatusToColour x:Key="MyConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: Can you still build your project successfully, or does that error stop a successful build?

Comment: When you start typing `c:` do you get IntelliSense? I'm asking because if you do, then just restart VS. I got a lot of these errors and restarting VS usually does it. Your code looks ok.

Comment: Clean, close VS, restart, rebuild.  Voila.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was going mad. I had to clean the project before the error disappeared.

Comment: Is your project source code on a network drive by any chance?

Comment: No it's on a local drive.

Comment: Ah... I ask because these problems can also be caused by code that resides on a network drive.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use full syntax with explicit assembly name, e.g:

```
xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:ProjectXYZ;assembly=ProjectXYZ"
```